# List directories in vxWorks ( FindFirstFile(<pattern>) / FindNext(<pattern>) )

Tags: filesystems, vxworks

How do I list a directory contents in vxWorks programmatically? I know about "ll" but it does not return me the list of directory entries neither does it return the "current" directory item (like FindFirstFile() / FindNextFile() in Windows).

I intend to implement the directory traversing on vxWorks (hrfs/dosfs).

Would be extra-nice if the solution covers the "wildcard" patterns like "*.txt" as well.

Answer (score 1):

VxWorks does not offer the convenience of `FindFirstFile(..)` and `FindNextFile(..)`.

I copy 'n pasted the following code together from an implementation I've made a few years ago:

```
#include <dirLib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#define MAX_PATH_LEN   256

typedef struct tag_file_list
{
   DIR *pDir;
   CHARS search[MAX_PATH_LEN];
} FILE_LIST;


STATUS findFirstFile(char *search, FILE_LIST *list, struct dirent *info)
{
   STATUS result = ERROR;

   if ((search != NULL) && (list != NULL))
   {
      list->pDir = opendir(search);
      if (list->pDir != NULL)
      {
         strcpy(list->search, search);   // remember root path!

         result = findNextFile(list, info);
      }
   }

   return (result);
}


STATUS findNextFile(FILE_LIST *list, struct dirent *info)
{
   STATUS result = ERROR;
   struct dirent *entry;
   char fullPath[MAX_PATH_LEN];

   if (list != NULL)
   {
      entry = readdir(list->pDir);
      if (entry  != NULL)
      {
         if (info != NULL)
         {
            /* build full path information to query file statistics */
            sprintf(fullPath, "%s/%s", list->search, entry->d_name);

            result = stat(fullPath, info);                
         }
         else
         {
            result = OK;
         }
      }
   }

   if (result == ERROR)
   {
      closedir(list->pDir);
      list->pDir = NULL;
   }

   return (result);
}


/* usage */
FILE_LIST fl;
struct dirent info;

if (findFirstFile("/tffs0", &fl, &info) == OK)
{
   do
   {
      /* process found file */
   }
   while (findNextFile(&fl, &info) != ERROR);
}
```

This is very basic and does not support wildcard patterns. This would be a nice thing to implement ;)

I didn't compile the code above but it should be enough to get you on track! Additionally the code is not safe concerning buffer overflows (string functions).